# Is there any scientific basis for Seasonal Affected Disorder (SAD)?

Tags: psychiatry

I've heard a lot of people claiming they they have a disorder called [Seasonal Affected Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_affective_disorder).

Is there any research that indicates this is an actual mental disorder?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_affective_disorder) provides a string of citations that show that it appears to be an actual disorder, though no mechanism is proposed if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @morganpdx As someone who used to suffer from this disorder every year (until I got myself a proper SAD lamp), I can definitely speak to its realness. I was SO happy when I learned that SAD was something that (for most people) is easily cured -- I've never looked back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes....Scientific research supports seasonal relationships with changes in mood....changes that can cause depressive episodes. As described by the [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/seasonal-affective-disorder/DS00195/DSECTION=symptoms) .....

> Seasonal affective disorder is a
>   cyclic, seasonal condition. This means
>   that signs and symptoms come back and
>   go away at the same time every year.
>   Usually, seasonal affective disorder
>   symptoms appear during late fall or
>   early winter and go away during the
>   sunnier days of spring and summer.
>   Some people have the opposite pattern
>   and become depressed with the onset of
>   spring or summer. In either case,
>   problems may start out mild and become
>   more severe as the season progresses.

I found the following bits on the research helpful for a start *(there is a lot of research...these are really small bits)*.....

From: [Re-Examining Seasonal Affective Disorder. Psychiatric Times. Vol. 19 No. 10. 2002](http://www.psychiatrictimes.com/display/article/10168/48376?pageNumber=3).

> The initial focus of the
>   pathophysiology of SAD was on
>   circadian rhythm theories, but
>   research interest has expanded to
>   include hypotheses related to
>   abnormalities in monoamine
>   neurotransmitters, personality and
>   genetics (Lam and Levitan, 2000;
>   Partonen and Magnusson, 2001)....
>
> .....Neurotransmitters and genetics. A
>   robust body of research also supports
>   the role of neurotransmitters such as
>   serotonin in the pathophysiology of
>   SAD (Neumeister et al., 2001a). For
>   example, neuroendocrine studies have
>   shown evidence for serotonergic
>   dysregulation in SAD.

From: [Seasonal effects on human striatal presynaptic dopamine synthesis. 2010](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21048126?tool=MedlinePlus)

*Sorry this is a bit long. I tried cutting it down....and failed.*

> Past studies in rodents have
>   demonstrated circannual variation in
>   central dopaminergic activity as well
>   as a host of compelling interactions
>   between melatonin--a
>   scotoperiod-responsive neurohormone
>   closely tied to seasonal
>   adaptation--and dopamine in the
>   striatum and in midbrain neuronal
>   populations with striatal projections.
>   In humans, seasonal effects have been
>   described for dopaminergic markers in
>   CSF and postmortem brain, and **there
>   exists a range of affective,
>   psychotic, and substance abuse
>   disorders that have been associated
>   with both seasonal symptomatic
>   fluctuations and dopamine
>   neurotransmission abnormalities**.
>   Together, these data indirectly
>   suggest a potentially crucial link
>   between circannual biorhythms and
>   central dopamine systems. *However,
>   seasonal effects on dopamine function
>   in the living, healthy human brain
>   have never been tested.* For this
>   study, 86 healthy adults underwent
>   (18)F-DOPA positron emission
>   tomography ([PET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography)) scanning, each at a
>   different time throughout the year.
>   Striatal regions of interest (ROIs)
>   were evaluated for differences in
>   presynaptic dopamine synthesis,
>   measured by the kinetic rate constant,
>   K(i), between fall-winter and
>   spring-summer scans. Analyses
>   comparing ROI average K(i) values
>   showed significantly greater putamen
>   (18)F-DOPA K(i) in the fall-winter
>   relative to the spring-summer group (p
>   = 0.038). Analyses comparing voxelwise K(i) values confirmed this finding and
>   evidenced intrastriatal localization
>   of seasonal effects to the caudal
>   putamen (p < 0.05, false-discovery
>   rate corrected), a region that
>   receives dopaminergic input
>   predominantly from the substantia
>   nigra. **These data are the first to
>   directly demonstrate a seasonal effect
>   on striatal presynaptic dopamine
>   synthesis and merit future research
>   aimed at elucidating underlying
>   mechanisms** and implications for
>   neuropsychiatric disease and new
>   treatment approaches.

[Spectral quality of light modulates emotional brain responses in humans.](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/45/19549.abstract)

> Light therapy can be an effective
>   treatment for mood disorders,
>   suggesting that light is able to
>   affect mood state in the long term. As
>   a first step to understand this
>   effect, we hypothesized that light
>   might also acutely influence emotion
>   and tested whether short exposures to
>   light modulate emotional brain
>   responses. During functional magnetic
>   resonance imaging, 17 healthy
>   volunteers listened to emotional and
>   neutral vocal stimuli while being
>   exposed to alternating 40-s periods of
>   blue or green ambient light. Blue
>   (relative to green) light increased
>   responses to emotional stimuli in the
>   voice area of the temporal cortex and
>   in the hippocampus. **During emotional
>   processing, the functional
>   connectivity between the voice area,
>   the amygdala, and the hypothalamus was
>   selectively enhanced in the context of
>   blue illumination**, which shows that
>   responses to emotional stimulation in
>   the hypothalamus and amygdala are
>   influenced by both the decoding of
>   vocal information in the voice area
>   and the spectral quality of ambient
>   light. These results demonstrate the
>   acute influence of light and its
>   spectral quality on emotional brain
>   processing and identify a unique
>   network merging affective and ambient
>   light information.

Comment: It's most certainly real. I had it my entire life until I got a Light-Based alarm clock. Now I NEVER get it (and in some ways I kind of miss it, because it makes me think of winter -- but then I remember how blue I felt and I don't!).

Comment: I moved to Australia. More expensive than an alarm clock, but also works pretty well.